# What time complexity does this graph represent?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, amortized-analysis

I was trying to find the amortized time complexity of my algorithm ,but when I exported the data to a csv file and drew a graph this is what I came up with. I am trying to achieve an amortized time complexity of O(logn) ,but this clearly isn't the case. What time complexity is this?

[image]

Comment: What is `n`? Can you say a bit more about your algorithm? How did you generate this data? The spikes in this curve are most likely an artifact. You know that we sometimes talk about "worst-case", "best-case", "average case", etc. Apparently, for some values of `n`, your algorithm handled the data more efficiently than for other values. This might be for a lot of reasons and is not necessarily meaningful for the worst-case or for more realistic input.

Comment: The graph itself approximates the line `T(n)/n = n/10` which means `T(n) = n*n/10`, which means the algorithm is O(n^2).

Comment: Basically given a bst I have to balance some sub trees of it given some criteria so that inserting and deleting nodes has an amortized time complexity of O(logn). After messing with my code I found the issue. My algorithm was correct ,but I was giving it input that was sorted. Like I gave it as input every number from 0 till 9000 ,but the numbers were in order. I used the rand() function and I came up with a graph that resembles log(n).

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks a lot ,I also thought it looked like O(n^2) ,but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What time complexity is this?

Without sharing your data or algorithm, it's hard to say anything for sure, but based on the picture alone **it looks like O(n<sup>2</sup>) to me.**

Your graph plots the function `S(n) = T(n) / n` and the tops of the peaks look roughly co-linear, so I'm going to assume that `S(n)` is `O(n)`. Then `T(n) = n * S(n) = n * O(n) = O(n^2)`.